Using Python to group similar values from pair combinations
I have a list of paired values. Values in each pair are declared as similar, meaning two values are considered similar if they appear together in a pair from the list. My goal is to create a list of clusters of similar values.
For example, here is the list I have:
col_combi = [('a','b'), ('b','c'), ('d','e'), ('l','j'), ('c','g'), 
             ('e','m'), ('m','z'), ('z','p'), ('t','k'), ('k', 'n'), 
             ('j','k')]

The similarity implies that "a" is similar to "b," "b" is similar to "c," and so on.
The final desired output is:
'a-b-c-g',
'd-e-m-z-p',
'l-j-k-n-t'

I tried using the networkx library, but I couldn't get it to work.

Not sure what you are going for, but assuming "similarity"
means a bidirectional edge between the two characters, you can create an adjacency graph and perform a depth first search in order to cluster similarity.
Next time please show what you have tried before posting a question (like specifically, not just "I tried using the networkx library"). The SO community is not here to write code for you... we are here to figure out specific problems. Nevertheless, I wrote some untested code to give you an idea.
col_combi = [('a','b'), ('b','c'), ('d','e'), ('l','j'), ('c','g'), ('e','m'), ('m','z'), ('z','p'), ('t','k'), ('k', 'n'), ('j','k')]

adj = {}

for item in col_combi:
    if item[0] not in adj.keys():
        adj[item[0]] = []
    if item[1] not in adj.keys():
        adj[item[1]] = []
    adj[item[0]].append(item[1])
    adj[item[1]].append(item[0])
visited = set()

curr = []
def dfs(node):
    curr.append(node)
    visited.add(node)
    if adj.get(node) != None:
        for neighbor in adj.get(node):
            if neighbor not in visited:
                dfs(neighbor)
clutter = []
for value in adj.keys():
    if (value not in visited):
        dfs(value)
        delim = ""
        for node in curr:
            print(delim + node, end = "")
            delim = "-"
        print(" ")
        curr = []


To accomplish this task using networkx, we need to know how to create an undirected graph and extract its connected components. The first step can be achieved with from_edgelist, and the second one with connected_components:
from networkx import from_edgelist, connected_components

col_combi = [('a','b'), ('b','c'), ('d','e'), ('l','j'), ('c','g'), 
             ('e','m'), ('m','z'), ('z','p'), ('t','k'), ('k', 'n'), 
             ('j','k')]

clusters = [*connected_components(from_edgelist(col_combi))]

Let's see the resulting clusters:
print(clusters)

# [{'a', 'b', 'c', 'g'}, {'d', 'e', 'm', 'p', 'z'}, {'j', 'k', 'l', 'n', 't'}]

print('\n'.join('-'.join(sorted(x)) for x in clusters))

# a-b-c-g
# d-e-m-p-z
# j-k-l-n-t

